# Android - How to check if 2 requests are same in Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have checked if requests are same using their hashcodes.

```
final Request original = chain.request();
MyLog.log(original.hashCode());
```

However, they are different:

> 245712287 144127529

When I tried to create a class which extends okhttp3.Request, I got an error:

> Cannot inherit from final 'okhttp3.Request'

Are there other ways to check if requests are same?

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Created helper class, which returns Request hashcode

```
public class RetrofitUtil {

    public static long hashcode(Request request){

        String url = request.url().url().toString();
        String body = getRequestBodyAsString(request.body());

        long result = url != null ? url.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + body != null ? body.hashCode() : 0;
        return result;

    }

    public static String getRequestBodyAsString(final RequestBody requestBody) {
        try {
            final RequestBody copy = requestBody;
            final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            if (copy != null)
                copy.writeTo(buffer);
            String requestBodyAsString = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(buffer.readUtf8(), "UTF-8");
            return requestBodyAsString;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```